# What is happening in the recursive method to get nth Fibonacci

Tags: java, recursion

The following is a recursive method to get the `nth` Fibonacci number.

```
  static int getNthFib(int n) {
    if (n < 2) return 1;
    return getNthFib(n - 2) + getNthFib(n - 1);
  }
```

If I pass 5 it will return 5, the fifth element in the Fibonacci sequence.

```
0 1 1 2 3 5
```

[image]

But when I try to understand what is actually happening in this recursive call and draw out each method call I expect it to return 8. Isn't the following diagram the method call stack, and if it is why isn't the answer 13?

**NOTE**

I have edited the image, the original was wrong. But if I add up all the numbers for this one the answer comes out to 8. Although the implementation is incorrect, why does it return 5 instead of 8?

Comment: F(0) is 0, not 1.

Comment: @Nevay no it isn't, unless 0 is somehow not less than 2

Comment: @OrangeDog The posted method is incorrect, F(1) and F(2) are 1, F(0) is 0, F(-1) is 1, F(-2) is -1 etc.

Comment: @Nevay The question is not about the correctness of the function definition, but the correctness of the diagram.

Comment: The point is that it **should** be 0.  If you used input "2" you would get 2 instead of 1 with this algorithm

Comment: Yes, but the reason the diagram doesn't match the implementation isn't because the implementation also happens to be wrong.

Comment: @OrangeDog yes you are correct the implemtation is wrong and the first diagram was wrong, how about now. It seems even the wrong implementation should return 8 instead of 5 ?

Comment: "If I pass 5 it will return 5" - did you test it, because it actually returns 8 just like your diagram now says.

Answer (score 5):

Your left subtree is wrong, F(3) should branch out to F(2) and F(1).
[image]

Morever F(0) should be zero instead of one, since if there are no elements sum should return as zero.(Modify base case)

As suggested in comments, and Based on your new question If you need to find fibonacci series. Try plotting tree with following code, It should give you correct results.

```
static int getNthFib(int n) {
    //change the return statement to return n, rather than return 0.
    if (n < 2) **return n**;
    return getNthFib(n - 2) + getNthFib(n - 1);
}
```

Comment: I don't know why you got downvoted. You've got freehand red circles and everything.

Comment: Even more obvious when the number goes up again: `F(5) -> F(3) -> F(4)`

Comment: why arent those valid ? the algorithm is if its not less than 2 it has to call again with (f3) - f(4)

Comment: It does call f(3) and f(4) but in the 2nd level from top. When you go down each level, you are subtracting values so the numbers have to decrease.

Comment: @EduardoDennis if `n` is not less than two it calls with `n-2` and `n-1`. I hope you agree that `3-2=1` and `3-1=2`, neither of which equal `4`

Comment: Also try to remember that one entire side of the tree is evaluated before the other.

Comment: @TheManHasNoName can you take a look at my new image ?

Comment: @EduardoDennis, the code you have given when executed gives 8 as the output when I run it, If you want a 5 instead which would be the Fibonacci series, modify code as suggested in the edited answer.

Comment: @pjs yeah that would work. I have used your suggestion in edit, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If we look at the definition of [Fibonacci numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number) we have:

F(0)=0

F(1)=1

F(n)=F(n-1)+F(n-2) for every n >= 2

So for the base case we should write something like this:

```
if (n = 0) return 0;
if (n = 1) return 1;
```

As for the diagram, I see two problems:

- the left subtree expands F(3) as F(3)+F(4) (see TheManHasNoName's answer)
- F(0) should be 0, not 1

Below the code according to what I have just written.

```
  static int getNthFib(int n) {
    if (n<2) return n;      // Here I assume that n >=0
    return getNthFib(n - 2) + getNthFib(n - 1);
  }
```